# Segmentation fault when running XFRESCO

Tags: segmentation-fault

I'm a research scholar and trying to run XFRESCO- a GUI for theoretical model code that I have to use for my calculations.

Whenever I try to use XFRESCO and reach the tab of partitions and then on states, if I click on any of the buttons-add,replace or so (same is happening in the coupling tab as well) XFRESCO closes abruptly and a message is displayed SEGMENTATION ERROR. (pics attached)

Please help me out with a solution.

[image: after hitting add/replace on partition tab]

[image: XFRESCO-GUI]

Comment: The author of XFresco has an email address on his website to report bugs: http://personales.us.es//moro/xfresco/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately there are too many possible reasons for a segfault, so there isn't much information we can work with. Consider reinstalling the software or filing a bug report with the devs.